# Unity gets stuck at final state of build

Tags: unity-game-engine

Yesterday my Unity was working just fine but today Unity gets stuck at "Done" phase of build. It successfully builds and I'm able to play the .exe file and everything works fine there but Unity itself gets stuck at following image:

[image]

My Task manager says Unity is doing nothing:

[image]

Reopening Unity lets me continue coding etc. but everytime I build it gets stuck at "Done". Any way to fix this?

I'm using Unity 5.4.1f1.

Comment: does it let you click on Cancel at the end?

Comment: No it does not. Restarting computer don't work either. And this happens after every build.

Comment: @Jonathan What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: one thing you can try is to look into an editor log file. after you have this experience restart unity, then at the top-right corner of the console window click on the dropdown > Open Editor Log. Try to find something suspicious there. Should be towards the end of the file.

Comment: Version 5.4.1f1

Comment: @Jonathan You could try updating Unity if you don't find any solution.

Comment: yep, best option would be to update.
P.S: your issue might as well be related to this: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/postprocessbuild-path-erroneous-with-unity-5-dot-4-in-some-cases

Comment: Maybe I should update then. Do you guys know has there been some big changes between versions 5.4.1f1 and 5.4.4f1 that will break my project?

Comment: @Jonathan Not to sure but you should backup your project and if anything goes wrong you can always go back to 5.4.1f1.